# Spring-test HttpFirewall is blocking requests from threads other than MAIN

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

I'm having some trouble while testing out one of my controllers.

When trying to make a mock request inside of a `Thread` instance using `thread.start()`, apparently, the `HttpFirewall` which is declared inside of the `FilterChainProxy` is filtering my request as `org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledRequest`.

Every codeline after the `mock.perform(req)` line was never executed, the Controller method was never invoked, I could never knew what happened with that Thread and a log was given by the logger (while the `MockMvc mock` instance is trying to perform the `req` I assume):

`2021-03-26 15:43:35.252 DEBUG 6972 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /file/image/bytes`

This was not the case when I tried to make the mock request directly in the test method, which is executed in the MAIN thread, the request came through, Controller method was invoked and the result was as predicted.

Here is the code which I used to test the Controller method in `Thread-1`:

```
@Test
public void testGetImageBytes() throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final UserRequestPostProcessor ADMIN = user("admin").roles("ADMIN");
            RequestBuilder req = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/file/image/bytes").with(ADMIN);
            MvcResult result;

            try {
                ResultActions action = mock.perform(req);
                // following lines were never executed
                result = action.andReturn(); 

                MockHttpServletResponse res = result.getResponse();

                Assert.isTrue(res.getStatus() == HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Resquest failed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

I'm very confused about the fact that my endpoint was being secured against requests by which other Threads than MAIN executed. Any suggestions would be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If this is a case of thread not returning and your program/test execution being blocked forever then that sounds like a deadlock situation. Capture threaddump when it is is blocked state and see what thread-1 is doing. However what I suspect here is that you are starting a thread in unit test but then aren't waiting for it to finish. For the main thread where unit test executes there is nothing to do after `thread.start()` and hence it finishes and program/test execution terminates before mock request can be executed.

Comment: I am aware that since there's no code after `thread.start()`, not thing was executed in the MAIN thread. It's just that there should've been at least some response from the endpoint, even though the `FilterChainProxy` clearly rejected the request. Maybe there is some deadlock some where as you mentioned.